# How to Upload webp Image in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, google-pagespeed, webp

Google Webpage speed Give guide lines upload Image in webp format. Then Increase page speed.

In Wordpress CMS not accept webp file.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code at the end of the config.php file. Your problem will be solved

```
//** *Enable upload for webp image files.*/
function webp_upload_mimes($existing_mimes) {
    $existing_mimes['webp'] = 'image/webp';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter('mime_types', 'webp_upload_mimes');
```

Comment: This is unnecessary since wp 5.8: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/07/wordpress-5-8-adds-webp-support/

Comment: and you might want to double check is the uploading file is really a webp image: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323221/allowing-webp-uploads

Answer (score 0):

Hi do you ONLY need to upload the .webp images to wordpress? NOT display them?
if you just wanna upload the images, then go to **wp-config.php** and add one line to it:

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

then you can go to media library and upload the images,

[image: images can be uploaded]

however if you want to also display these images, here are some tools([useful article link][2]) that you may need to use, such as : **cache enabler**,

if any further questions please leave a comment. :)

Comment: where's the *useful article link* ?

Comment: In case you want to see the thumbnails too, you can use the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447139/3840840

Comment: Enabling `ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS` might be dangerous since it will allow a user to upload any file with arbitrary mime type into your media library. If you only want to allow upload files with mime `image/webp`, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67321737, or just upgrade to wp 5.8 or newer.