# Wordpress webp image previews

Tags: php, wordpress

I have updated wordpress using the following code to allow for webp uploads,

```
function webp_upload_mimes( $existing_mimes ) {
    $existing_mimes['webp'] = 'image/webp';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter( 'mime_types', 'webp_upload_mimes' );
```

Which works great, but the webp images do not show a preview in the media selector, as shown

[image]

Is there anyway I can force wordpress to render webp previews? By the time my site is done, it could potentially have hundreds of webp images, not being able to see them when selecting could be a huge pain!

Comment: While it's an interesting idea, I would definitely not recommend doing so as Internet Explorer to this date has [no support](https://caniuse.com/#search=webp) for the webp image format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update July 2021**

> From WordPress version 5.8 forward, you can upload and use WebP images in WordPress like you would a JPEG or PNG image today (as long as your hosting service supports WebP). Switching to the WebP format for your images will improve your site’s performance and your site visitor’s experience.
> https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/07/wordpress-5-8-adds-webp-support/

---

I found a solution to show the thumbnails on the media manager. You have to add the following code to the `functions.php` of your active theme:

```
//enable upload for webp image files.
function webp_upload_mimes($existing_mimes) {
    $existing_mimes['webp'] = 'image/webp';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter('mime_types', 'webp_upload_mimes');

//enable preview / thumbnail for webp image files.
function webp_is_displayable($result, $path) {
    if ($result === false) {
        $displayable_image_types = array( IMAGETYPE_WEBP );
        $info = @getimagesize( $path );

        if (empty($info)) {
            $result = false;
        } elseif (!in_array($info[2], $displayable_image_types)) {
            $result = false;
        } else {
            $result = true;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
add_filter('file_is_displayable_image', 'webp_is_displayable', 10, 2);
```

---

The `webp_is_displayable` function is using the [`file_is_displayable_image`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/file_is_displayable_image/) hook and checks if the file (on `$path`) is a `webp` image file. To check for the `webp` image file the function is using the constant [`IMAGETYPE_WEBP`](http://php.net/manual/de/image.constants.php#constant.imagetype-webp).

Comment: Brilliant, this works great! Just for anyone else who uses this method, don't get confused when all of your current webp images don't start showing, this method only starts to work for newly uploaded webp's after adding this function!

Comment: Works like a charm. What adjustment do I need to make if I want to make SVG displayable?

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Sebastian Brosch is still working.
But as S_R commented, the old webp images won't have a working preview.
For that, you can use the wordpress plugin "Force Regenerate Thumbnails" to reload old images and create previews.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, if you want WordPress to allow you to upload webp to the media/library you can use this code:

```php
//** Enable upload for webp image files.
function webp_upload_mimes($existing_mimes) {
    $existing_mimes['webp'] = 'image/webp';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter('mime_types', 'webp_upload_mimes');
```